# Replacing a variable with another

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I've changed my code a bit and I still can't quite figure it out.

User input: !change Hi

```
var A = "Hello"

if (msg.content.includes ('!change')) {
  A = msg.content.replace('!change ', '');
}
msg.send(A); //the change won't stick outside the if statement
```

Output: Hello

I did some reading and also tried using a function but I couldn't get that to work.

```
var A = "Hello"

if (msg.content.includes ('!change')) {
  B = msg.content.replace('!change ', '');

  changetext(B)
}


function changetext(altText){
A=altText
}

msg.send(A); //the change won't stick here either
```

Sorry if I am not being overly clear, I am trying my best lol. My goal is to have it so a user can input "!change Hi" and then the change will stay outside the if statement and A="Hi". Hopefully that makes sense. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your `if` statement inside a function in your real code?  If so, the `var` in front of `var A = C` is declaring a new and separate `A` variable.  If you want to modify the top level `A`, then remove the `var` from `var A = C` so it's just `A = C`.  FYI, your three lines of code could be replaced with `A = msg.content.replace('!change ', '');`.  You don't need `B` or `C`.

Comment: I updated my code and tried to clarify on what I am trying to do, I did use the change and eliminated B and C and just went with A off the bat. I'm still a bit confused though

Comment: I don't know what to say.  Your code works just fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fub72ac6/.  Perhaps `msg.content` isn't what you think it is?

Comment: @Cody have you tried using the debugger or stepping through your code manually? It looks like the jsfiddle posted above should work.

What happens when you call `msg.send(A)` within `changeText`?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want your `var A` to be the contents of `var C`.

The reason why you won't get the expected output in `msg.send(A)` outside of the `if` block, but you do inside the `if` block, is because you're defining an entirely new variable `A` within the if block, so that the last call to `msg.send` will always return 'Hello'.

Try removing the `var` and just using `A = C`, this should give you the correct output

e.g

```
 var A = "Hello"
 if (msg.content.includes('!change')) {
   var B = msg.content;
   var C = B.replace('!change ', '');
   A += C;

   msg.send(A); //Hi Hello
 }

 msg.send(A); //Hi Hello
```

Comment: This is a guess (it might be a correct guess based on code the OP didn't show).  The OP's code doesn't actually show the top level `A` in a different function scope from the second `var A`.  `var A` in the same function scope does not actually create a new variable.

Comment: He wants A + C i think, i deleted my answer om behalf of your explanation good work

Comment: That's a good point @jfriend00, it most likely is in a function or there is other code that is overwriting `var A`

@DutchPrime, yeah I see the code output example now from OPs post

Comment: @ShermanHui thanks for the advice, I actually didn't know that I was essentially making a whole new variable. I changed my code a bit but I am still unable to do what I am trying to do, I also tried to clarify my goal a bit better.